# Error: this application requires the latest version of Google Play services for AR

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I'm making an app using sceneform (1.17.1), but when I launch it, this message appears: "This application requires the latest version of Google Play services for AR."

I don't think my device is causing the problem (Pixel 3a XL, Android 11), and the Google Play services for AR app doesn't need updating.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have build and run directly from unity code is working but integrating on Flutter facing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I add following code to app/ build.gradle i don't know but its working without update ar.

```html
  Add to app build.gradle

    //sceneform
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:assets:1.15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.29.0

 and add root/build.gradle to dependencies this line 
 
    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after testing on another device (Galaxy S9, Android 10), it seems like the problem was with my device.